# Find xpath of input element based on entered text

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I have a page which appears with some pre-filled data in input boxes. I want to select the input box which has my desired content, based on the content itself. This content isn't part of page HTML, but rather appears as `value` attribute in the element properties.

I have written a simple HTML file (test.html) to demonstrate the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Hello </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <input type="text"> <br> <br>
        <input type="text"> <br> <br>
        <input type="text"> <br> <br>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let input_nodes = document.querySelectorAll("input")
        for(var i = 0; i < input_nodes.length; i++) {
            input_nodes[i].value = 'value_' + i;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

On this page I want to select the element with entered value as `value_1`. It doesn't appear in page HTML, but can be seen in element properties.
[image]

Comment: I see that you've created a sample `test.html`, is it possible to share that as well ?

Comment: @cruisepandey The HTML code present in question is the entire content of `test.html` file.

Comment: okay, see below. You should tag your binding language as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using `test.html` file in my local, I could see **3 input box** in UI

[image]

As you can see this xpath

```
//div[@id='test']//input[2]
```

represent the node that you've been looking to do `send_keys`

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. The index of input element is not known (this test html is just an example). We need to find the element based on the already entered value. Something like `//input[@value='value_1']` (doesn't work, just used to show the intent of question)

Comment: If it is not present in `HTMLDOM`, you can not have a locator for that. Having said that, you should be using `JavaScriptExecutor` to extract the value off of an input tag.

Comment: Are the attributes (properties) of a HTML node not part of DOM? Makes me wonder what is the relationship between HTML of page and the DOM.

Comment: If you could edit your answer to clearly explain why xpath can't access those properties, then I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: In General the value_1 that you are seeing, they should be placeholder attribute in HTML. But in this particular case to me it seems that we are getting `value_1`  from this JS code that you've shared: `<script type="text/javascript">
        let input_nodes = document.querySelectorAll("input")
        for(var i = 0; i < input_nodes.length; i++) {
            input_nodes[i].value = 'value_' + i;
        }
    </script>`

Comment: You can probably read this variable into your automation code `input_nodes` and that should tell you upfrontly that we will have n number of input element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String preFilledValue = "value_1";
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='test']/input"));
        for (WebElement ele : elements) {
            if (preFilledValue.equals(ele.getAttribute("value"))) {
                System.out.println("Element found");
            }
        }
    }
```